# IOS - Translucent Navigation Bar over content

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a `tableView` with a `UIImage` in the header. What I what to accomplish is the same as twitters profile page. A translucent navigation bar over the cover image. All I have done so far is `navigationBar.translucent = true` and set my `coverImage.frame.origin.x = -50` but the navigationBar still does not go over my image and the image just gets cut off. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITableViewController` adjusts its content inset so the start of its content begins at the bottom edge of the navigation bar.

You can uncheck the view controller's **Adjust Scroll View Insets** property, to stop the tableView content from being inset.  (This will affect both top and bottom bars.)

Comment: thanks for the help but this didn't work, my `UITableView` header is still below the navigation bar @PetahChristian

Comment: If you use Storyboard, please post a screenshot showing the view hierarchy.  Please also show any code where you are creating or changing the related views.

Comment: It was a combination of **Adjust Scroll View Insets** and **Under Top Bars**. Thanks @PetahChristian

Comment: Great!  Normally they're both checked for tableView controllers, so the table's rows can scroll under the bar, but the first or last rows aren't hidden by the bars.